# How to convert an array to a list

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have an array filled with consecutive numbers starting from 1:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numOfValues = in.nextInt();
    int[] array = new int[numOfValues];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = i + 1;               
    }
```

How can I convert this array to a list?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: List list = Arrays.asList(array);

Comment: @MahenderYadav That will create a `List` with one element, regardless of the number of elements in the `int[]`.